# particles.js - edge, slow-down effect

Tags: javascript, particles.js

I found this website [CLICK](https://jakefrederick.com/#) and noticed the animation on the right side. I was trying to do it on my own but i failed, so I kept looking for some already written codes and found particles.js. It seems very similar, however particles in particles.js just leave the screen or bounce back. Particles on that website don't bounce, they just slow down and return back. Does anyone know how to achieve such an effect? Any help appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example site, it appears the particles are rebounding, but from an off-screen border.  Create a canvas that extends off of the right side of the screen and constrain the particles to that border by setting out_mode attribute to bounce like:

"move": {
...
  "out_mode": "bounce",
...
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is actually something I don't want. That "hard" bounce. I would love to achieve effect of particles not even touching left side.